# Opacity from RGB array

Tags: arrays, image, image-processing, colors

So I'm no expert in coding: I just have a vague understanding of a few bits and bobs.

I understand that images of pixel dimensions X*Y are stored in array of size 3*X*Y where each vector pulled from a given (x,y) value has 3 elements for the 3 RGB values.

I also understand that one can also store an image in a 4*X*Y array, where each pulled vector now has 4 values, RGBA with A being Alpha, used to represent the opacity of a particular pixel.

Now I'm into animation, and have pencil drawings of white clouds on a black background that I want to import into Flash. I would like the blacker parts of the drawing to be more transparent and the lighter parts to be more opaque. I have the scans of the drawings saved in .png format.

If I had any idea how to manipulate an image at the 'array level', I could have a stab at this myself but I'm at a loss.

I need a program that, given a .png image and a reference RGB value {a b c}, obtains the RGB array of the image and converts it into an RBGA array ***such that:***

a pixel of RGB value {p q r}

**...... Becomes ......**

a pixel of RGBA value {p q r 1-M[(|p-a|^2 + |q-b|^2 + |r-c|^2)^1/2]}.

Where M is a normalisation factor which makes the largest alpha value = 1.

i.e. M = 1/[(255^2 + 255^2 + 255^2)^1/2]) = 0.0026411...

i.e. the alpha value of the replacement pixel is the 'distance' between the colour of the pixel and some reference colour which can be input.

This then needs to export the new RGBA Array as a png image.

Any ideas or any fellow animators know if this can be done directly with actionscript?

---

**Example:** Reference = {250 251 245}

RGB array =

|{250 251 245} {250 250 250}|

|{30 255 22}    {234 250 0 }|

**...... Becomes ......**

RGBA array =

|{250 251 245 1} {250 251 245 0.987}|

|{30 255 22 0.173} {234 250 0 0.352}|

Comment: You seem to have a handle on the math involved, what's the hangup? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: No I know, it's just I have no idea how to actually implement it. I've only done like basics of coding in Matlab so I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: Sounds interesting... how about some sample images to play with?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite simply, just at the command-line, with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for free on OSX and Windows.

The *"secret sauce"* is the `-fx` operator - described [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php).

So, let's generate a 300x200 black image and then use `-fx` to calculate the red channel so that the red varies across the image according to what fraction of the width (`w`) we are from the left side (`i`):

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:black -channel R -fx 'i/w'  result.png
```

[image]

Note that I am generating an image *"on-the-fly"* with `-size 300x200 xc:black`, whereas if you have a PNG file with your animation frame in it, you can put that in, in its place.

Now let's say we want to vary the opacity/alpha too - according to the distance down the image from the top:

```
 convert -size 300x200 xc:black -alpha on \
    -channel R -fx 'i/w'                  \
    -channel A -fx 'j/h' result.png
```

[image]

Ok, we are getting there... your function is a bit more complicated, so, rather than typing it on the command-line every time, we can put it in a script file called `RGB2Opacity.fx` like this:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:black -alpha on -channel A -fx @RGB2Opacity.fx result.png
```

where `RGB2Opacity.fx` is simple and looks like this for the moment:

```
0.2
```

Now we need to put your *"reference"* pixel on the command line with your animation frame so that **ImageMagick** can work out the difference. That means your actual command-line will look more or less exactly like the following:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:"rgb(250,251,245)" YourImage.png -alpha on -channel A -fx @RGB2Opacity.fx result.png
```

And then we need to implement your formula in the `-fx` script file. Your variable names must be at least 2 letters long with no digits in them, and you should return a single value for the opacity. Variables are all scaled between [0,1.0] so your 255 scaling is a little different. I have no sample image and I am not sure how the answer is supposed to look, but it will be pretty close to this:

```
MM=1/pow(3,0.5);
pmasq=pow((u.r-v.r),2.0);
qmbsq=pow((u.g-v.g),2.0);
rmcsq=pow((u.b-v.b),2.0);
1-MM*pow((pmasq+qmbsq+rmcsq),0.5)
```

I don't know if/how to put comments in `-fx` scripts, so I will explain the variable names below:

- `pmasq` is the square of `p` minus `a`.
- `qmbsq` is the square of `q` minus `b`.
- `rmcsq` is the square of `r` minus `c`.
- `u.r` refers to the red channel of the *first* image in **ImageMagick**'s list, i.e. the red channel of your reference pixel.
- `v.g` refers to the green channel of the *second* image in **ImageMagick**'s list, i.e. the green channel of your animation frame.

Let's create your animation frame now:

```
convert xc:"rgb(250,251,245)" xc:"rgb(250,250,250)" xc:"rgb(30,255,22)" xc:"rgb(234,250,0)" +append frame.png
```

[image]

And check it looks correct:

```
convert frame.png txt:
```

**Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,srgb
0,0: (64250,64507,62965)  #FAFBF5  srgb(250,251,245)
1,0: (64250,64250,64250)  #FAFAFA  grey98
2,0: (7710,65535,5654)  #1EFF16  srgb(30,255,22)
3,0: (60138,64250,0)  #EAFA00  srgb(234,250,0)
```

If we apply that to your image and check the results, you can see I have got it slightly wrong somewhere, butI'll leave you (or some other bright spark) to work that out...

```
convert -size 4x1 xc:"rgb(250,251,245)" frame.png -alpha on -channel A -fx @RGB2Opacity.fx result.png

convert result.png txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,srgba
0,0: (64250,64507,62965,65535)  #FAFBF5FF  srgba(250,251,245,1)
1,0: (64250,64507,62965,64764)  #FAFBF5FC  srgba(250,251,245,0.988235)
2,0: (64250,64507,62965,19018)  #FAFBF54A  srgba(250,251,245,0.290196)
3,0: (64250,64507,62965,29041)  #FAFBF571  srgba(250,251,245,0.443137)
```